# Computing the enclosed area formed by a curve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

> Given the following curve:
>
> ${(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2})}^2=\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}$, $a,b>0$
>
> Find the space enclosed by it.

Now, obviously (I think) the idea is to subsitute $y=brsin\theta$ and $x=arcos\theta$, and you get the equation:

> $r^2=cos(2\theta)$

From here we should perform double integration, I assume. I thought of:

> $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{cos2\theta}r^2 drd\theta$

However that obviously ends up as 0. The problem is, even if I try to take into consideration the symmetry with:

> $4\times \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{cos2\theta}r^2 drd\theta$

It still ends up as 0. Am I computing it wrong, or is my double-integral wrong? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $r^2=\cos{2\theta}$ then $r$ is from $0$ to $\sqrt{\cos{2\theta}}$

Comment: That's a simple flaw - the main issue here is the range-defining?

Comment: No, if you see the graph of $r^2=\cos{2\theta}$ you would see that the point in $(1,0)$ is when $\theta=0$ and  the origin is hitted for the first time is in $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Then it's still slightly unclear to me.

Comment: I post an answer I hope is clear now and it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the integral in polar coordinates is:

$$A=\iint_T r\;\mathrm{d}r\;\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Second is more clear if you see the graph of the area:

[image]

And observe the next:

In the first quadrant $\theta$ goes from $0$ (point $(1,0)$)  to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ (point $(0,0)$).

Second when $\theta$ goes from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ $\cos{2\theta}$ is negative therefore the square of the distance to the origin is not well defined.

The same with $\theta$ from  $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Third from $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ to $\pi$ you have the part of the curve which in the second quadrant.

I think you can continue and define the rest of the curve when is well defined.

But you can take advantage of the simmetry and just take the first quadrant and calculate:

$$A=4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_0^{\sqrt{\cos{2\theta}
}} r\;\mathrm{d}r\;\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Comment: Thank you! That clarified it!